# Looking for a generic way to handle Linq reports & return results in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, generics, anonymous-types

I'm designing a reporting engine for my project.  The project will have several reports, each of which can be expressed as a Linq query; some will have parameters, while others won't.

Now in order to meet my clients' requirements, I need to return the results of the queries in XML format, so that they can apply an XSL transform to make it look pretty according to their own taste.

So, my plan thus far is to have an abstract `Report` base class, from which all my reports will be derived.  The base class will need the following methods:

```
public virtual void SetParameter(string ParameterName, object Value) {
  throw new NotImplementedException("This report does not accept parameters.");
}

public abstract object GetData(); // what return type?

public XElement GetXMLData() {
  // calls GetData() and uses some kind of reflection to turn the data into XML?
}
```

To flesh this out a little more: `SetParameter()` is fairly self-explanatory.  `GetData()` is supposed to contain the Linq query, and return an `IEnumerable<'a>` type, where `'a` is the anonymous type of the final result.  But obviously you can't declare something as being of anonymous type, so I need some other generic way of relating to the results of my Linq query - one that will allow me to iterate through the returned fields and create an appropriate XML schema.

What should the return type of `GetData()` be?  How do I get the field names/values?  Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Is the data in a tabular format or are there child collections in the return as well?

Comment: Could be child collections in the return.  My code needs to work (recursively?) through all collections and turn the "primitive" type properties into XML.

Answer (score 1):

Is your data stored in SQL server?

If so why not use SQL Server Reporting Services? It comes "free" with SQL Server. It would be a lot more productive than building a report engine from scratch.

Comment: Because it is slow, you cannot bold, limited design ability, the pdf engine doesn't allow you to save pdf in non editable format, external customers cannot write and design their own look and feel, customers cannot write their own sql and generate reports...

Answer (score 1):

Could you make your base report class generic over the desired data type?

```
public class ReportBase<TEntity> {
    public virtual void SetParameter<T>(string ParameterName, T Value) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This report does not accept parameters.");
    }

    public abstract TEntity GetData();

    public XElement GetXmlData() {
      // calls GetData() and uses some kind of reflection to turn the data into XML?
    }
}
```

You could also restrict `TEntity` to be of some base type that exposes how to serialize itself, simplifying `GetXmlData`. Have you considered using .NET's built-in XML serialization features?